# Change root directory of Apache2

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2

sorry if this is simple but I looked everywhere online I still cannot find a solution. 
- I'm running ubuntu 14 and installed Apache2. 
- the problem is that I'm trying to change the root directory to my home directory.

- the original directory is /var/www/html and checking permission it belongs to root.
- I edited two files,
- sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
- sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

for the latter I changed, /var/www/html to my home/user1/wwww

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

at one point I even changed permssion of my home/user1/www to www-data:webdev ut I keep getting page forbidden.  Can anyone help with this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the ownership of the directories and files - you must allow the apache user to read the files in order for them to be served.  Be sure the available site is symlinked under enabled sites.

Comment: can you please elaborate apache user?  when I check the original /var/www/html it belongs to root. thanks.

Comment: If you use the command **ls -l /var/www** do you see **drwxr-xr-x** next to the html directory?